# Single click is not working in IOS for ionic app after updating cordova plugins to latest version

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Recently i updated all plugins to latest versions.But after that..single click is not working in IOS(only double tap is working).In android working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sry because initially i thought this problem because of plugins updates but the actual problem occurred as we added one script plugin, in that some reqEx is making the script as commented code in ios. By adding escape characters to the regEx we are able to resolve it.